# Does each PHP-FPM Worker individually load php.ini?

Tags: php

I installed PHP 5.3.8 from source on Ubuntu Natty. I also enabled FPM during configuration.

However, I've been having issues installing PHP extensions. When I add the extension to my php.ini file (e.g. `extension=apc.so`) and restart PHP (i.e. `/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart`), I get an error like the one below:

```
Starting php-fpm PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'apc' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  Module 'geoip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'geoip' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
```

My PHP-FPM conf is has the setting `pm.start_servers = 5`, so I have about 5 PHP-FPM workers active. Are they all trying to load the php.ini file when I restart PHP (hence the message that the module has already been loaded)?! If they are, is there a way I can prevent that to stop the errors as it the errors become fatal when I load Zend Loader?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a couple of hours I managed to find a way to remedy this. I guess this would be more beneficial to those compiling and installing PHP with FPM from source (All you apt-get people probably don't have anything to do with this)

Basically, it involves using your php-fpm.conf to load all your PHP extensions, instead of php.ini. Here's what you do:

1. Open your php-fpm.conf file (I installed my php from source so I have mine at `/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf` based on how I setup my `--prefix` and `--with-config-file-path`, but you can use `find / -name "php-fpm.conf"` from the bash shell to find where yours is).
2. Add your extension load directives (ideally at the end of the file). You need to be careful here as the format is a little different. In your php.ini file it would be like this `extension=apc.so`, but in your php-fpm.conf file it should be defined like this `php_admin_value[extension]=apc.so`.

NOTE: Make sure your `extension_dir` (where you kept all the .so files for your extensions) value is defined in your php.ini file. Then restart php-fpm.

I did the above and have no more errors, and all my extension show up in `phpinfo()`.

I hope this helps someone, it practically drove me crazy.

Cheers.

**EDIT**

After further testing I found that the issue was actually a little more complicated. It was being caused by PHP loading the php.ini twice as I had specified the same location for `--with-config-file-path` and `--with-config-file-scan-dir` at compile time.

So you would want to do the following as a better alternative to what I specified above (which also works but has a limitation as you will not be able to load Zend extensions e.g. IonCube Loader):

1. Compile PHP with the following option `--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php/etc/conf.d`. Make it is a different directory from `--with-config-file-path`.
2. Create a separate file for loading your PHP extensions (you can call it phpext.ini) and save it at the location defined above i.e. `/usr/local/php/etc/conf.d`. In this file, define all the extensions you want to load e.g. `extension=apc.so`. Your extensions should be saved in the `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/` directory, which should be the default directory I suppose. Make sure you don't define your extensions in the main php.ini file.
3. Restart PHP

Everything will work fine now and you will be able to load Zend Extensions (as they must be defined in your php.ini file and can't be in the php-fpm.conf).

Cheers.

Comment: Beautiful! I always wondered why php-fpm was cluttering my logs with module loading warnings ....

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses multiple confiugration files for PHP, often one per extension. If you install the extension via the system software management (e.g. apt), you don't need to manually enable the extension in the `php.ini` file.

If you remove the files you've added into `php.ini` this should solve your issue.

Additionally: PHP reads all ini files once per active process.

Comment: I installed all PHP and all the extensions from source, so I do have to enable them manually (I didn't use apt-get). They all work and show up in `phpinfo()`, but I get the errors. It's the ZendGuardLoader.so that causes a fatal error when it loads (apparently because it loads twice), the others just give the errors but the extension works.

Comment: From where have you obtained the sources and especially the build scripts?

Comment: Standard issue PHP: The PHP source files are from php.net, the php extensions are from PECL.

Answer (score 0):

Check that there aren't any geoip/apc sub-ini's in /etc/php5/conf.d. Ubuntu tends to load external drivers by sticking their .ini into that conf.d directory, and leaves the main .ini alone.

Comment: The only .ini file in the conf.d directory is pdo.ini, and it contains a single line `extension=pdo.so`. There's another php.ini file at `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` but from my phpinfo() the php.ini is being loaded from `/usr/local/php/etc/php.ini` (which the right .ini file)