# What is the right way to load a zend extension in the php-fpm.conf?

Tags: php

I'm trying to load the ioncube loader via the php-fpm.conf file.

I know you're probably wondering why I didn't use the php.ini, but it's a little complicated and you can see more of why here ([Does each PHP-FPM Worker individually load php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173959/does-each-php-fpm-worker-individually-load-php-ini)).

Anyway, I am loading my other extensions from this file (php-fpm.conf) using the following directive in the php-fpm.conf:

```
php_admin_value[extension]=<extension_name>.so
```

So for example, `php_admin_value[extension]=apc.so` loads APC from the `extension_dir` (which is defined in my php.ini). It works ok and solves a few issues I was having with defining extensions via the php.ini.

However, using the zend_extension directive does not work. So the following doesn't seem to work

```
php_admin_value[zend_extension]=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
```

Is there something I'm missing? I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does apache error log say?

Comment: @JohnCartwright I'm not using Apache, I'm using NGINX.

Answer (score 3):

you can only define a php file with php-fpm command

```
# copy php.ini, and enable all extensions here
cp /etc/php5/php.ini /etc/php5/my-php.ini
# copy fpm config and set a new pool dir
cp /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm-my-config.conf
# create a new pool conf and create a new start script
php-fpm -c /etc/php5/my-php.ini --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm-my-config.conf
```

thats all :)

had the same question, thats why i answered here ;-)

Comment: Perfect solution for my use-case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think Zend Extensions can only be loaded in the `php.ini`

Comment: Really?! I didn't know that. I guess I might have to forego using Zend Guard Loader or IonCube Loader. In PHP-FPM it causes a Fatal Error because the PHP-FPM workers are trying to load the php.ini multiples times, and I can't seem to figure out how to fix the situation. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there an /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini file that you can load it in?

Comment: I compiled PHP from source, as well as all the extensions I needed from PECL. I didn't use apt-get. I have a php.ini file but when I load it there, there seems to be some conflict with php-fpm because in the php-fpm.conf I have it set to create 5 workers...and I don't know for sure, but it seems like each pool is trying to load the php.ini, so when I restart php-fpm it tells me that the module (zend loader) has already been loaded, and then it fails.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't install FPM from apt-get?

Comment: I needed to use a specific PHP version and apt-get doesn't give you an option to do that.

Comment: As long as you have, say, the Hardy archives available: `sudo apt-get install php5=5.2.4-2ubuntu5.27`